# reorganize files inside a jar with ant

Tags: ant, jar, oracle-adf

I am currently deploying an oracle adf project using `ojdeploy`. Unfortunately the packaging of the jar is not as it should be.

So I have images in the paths

```
lookAndFeel.jar/skins/lightsOff/images
lookAndFeel.jar/skins/lightsOn/images
```

which I need to merge with

```
lookAndFeel.jar/META-INF/adf/skins/lightsOff/images
lookAndFeel.jar/META-INF/adf/skins/lightsOn/images
```

Is there a way to do this with ant?

**edit**

I read [Top 15 Ant Best Practices](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/17/ant_bestpractices.html) Point 13, where they state, that I should use `zipfileset`. But I was not able to do it that way, since my required files are already in the jar. The initial jar creation is done via `ojdeploy` therefor I don't have an influence on the initial structure of the jar.

Comment: Extract the jar (with unjar), move the files (with move), recreate the jar (with jar). Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @JBNizet doesn't that create too much overhead? Though, I would appreciate an example, since I am new to ant.

Comment: Try something first, and come back if you have a problem. Ant has an excellent documentation.

Comment: @JBNizet well came up with a solution, based on your suggestion. But still think there must be an cleaner way.. Though, thank you!

Comment: The cleaner way is to create the jar file with the right structure from the beginning. But that's not what you asked for, is it?

Comment: @JBNizet I think I can't, since `ojdeploy` does some undocumented magic, which might change with new versions. At least this is what I have read so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to understand what the issue is:

- Did you create this jar?
- Are you *merging* new data or moving it around?

As others have stated, you need to unjar, munge the results, and then jar it back up. No biggie:

```
<property name="target.dir"   value="${basedir}/target"/>
<property name="work.dir"     value="${target.dir}/work"/>
<property name="munge.dir"    value="${work.dir}/munge"/>

<target name="munge.jar">
    <unjar src="${jar.file}"
        dest="${munge.dir}"/>

    <here be dragons.../>

    <delete file="${jar.file}"/>

    <jar destfile="${jar.file}
       basedir="${munge.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Not being 100% sure what you want, you'll have to fill out the `<here be dragons.../>` part. You'll move, rename, shuffle, delete, and add to your heart's content.

Another possibility is to use the `<mapper/>` sub-entity to reformat your jar as you unjar it.

```
<target name="munge.jar">
    <unjar src="${jar.file}"
        dest="${munge.dir}">
        <mapper type="glob"
            from="skins/**/*"
            to="META-INF/adf/skins/**/*"/>
    </unjar>

    <delete file="${jar.file}"/>

    <jar destfile="${jar.file}
       basedir="${munge.dir}"/>
</target>
```

I haven't tested the above, but it'll give you an idea.

Comment: I read [Top 15 Ant Best Practices](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/17/ant_bestpractices.html) Point 13, where they state, that I should use `zipfileset`. But I was not able to do it that way, since my required files are already in the jar. The initial jar creation is done via `ojdeploy` therefor I don't have an influence on the initial structure of the jar.

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes So, you don't build the required jar. Does my reply on how to use `<unjar>` help in any way? Basically, you're going to have to _unzip_ and rebuild the jar. The `<mapper>` might make this easier.

Comment: Your first solution is similar to the one I created with the help of JB Nizet. So I think I am going to accept your answer.